# expression with inverses in modular equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

How to solve for $x \bmod m$ in :

$$((10210+18371\cdot 8642\cdot x)\cdot (x+2055)^{-1}) \equiv 4804  \mod {20983} $$

And I've found  $$(18371\cdot 8642) \equiv 4804 \mod{20983}$$

Comment: $20983$ is prime, so you're stuck with doing your work in that modulus. First job is to find out the value of $ 4804^{-1} \bmod 20983$. I suggest you do that and add to the question to show willing.

Comment: 4804^−1 mod 20983 is 20603

Comment: And [here is a guide (link)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format formulas etc.

Comment: Oh, unless I misread... what does the inverse (${}^{-1}$) refer to? Just the second term, or everything before the ${\bmod}$?

Comment: The inverse refer just to the second term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have

$$((10210+4804\cdot x)\cdot (x+2055)^{-1}) \equiv 4804  \mod {20983} \\
\implies 10210+4804\cdot x \equiv 4804(x+2055) \mod {20983} \\
\implies 10210 \equiv 4804\cdot 2055 \mod 20983$$

Which, as it happens, is true. So any value of $x$ will satisfy the equivalence, provided that $(x+2055)^{-1} \bmod 20983$ exists, which since $20983$ is prime, will be true unless $x\equiv -2055 \equiv 18928 \bmod 20983$.

Comment: Well, any value of $x$ such that $x+2055$ is invertible modulo 20983.

Comment: @GerryMyerson good point. I forget that with these big primes.

Comment: so at this point x cannot be found without the integer value of inverse  $$x+2055 mod 20983$$

Comment: The equation is true for any value of $x$ **except** $x\equiv 18928 \bmod 20983$